# Chrome doesn't properly recognize the back side.(HTML, CSS, backface-visibility: hidden)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Chrome doesn't properly recognize the back side.
I want to make front-face ==> digital clock / back-face ==> weather.
This is my [website](http://taemin-98.github.io/Clock).

On mobile Chrome, Safari ==> work. 
PC Chrome and Edge ==> doesn't work.

How to I fix it?

-----------------here is my summarized code----------

```
<div class=front/>
<div class=back/>

.front, .back{ position: absolute; backface-visibility: hidden; }
.back{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
```

Comment: Need debugging details. Errors, screenshots? Please add to the post with Edit

Answer (score 0):

Try with these CSS properties...

```
.ClockStyle {

 backface-visibility: visible;

}


.ClockTrans {

 transform-style: flat;

 transform-origin: 50% 50%;

 transform: rotateY(180deg);

 transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) 0s;
}
```

NB: Or whatever transition you prefer.

Comment: It doesn't work. My problem is Chrome doesn't properly recognize the back side. I want to show front side: disital clock, back side: weather. If I use' backface-visibility: visible', on front side show both side(clock&weather).